# Resizing Panel using its center as anchor point

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

I'm trying to Resize a panel using a Resize Effect using its center as the anchor point. I've been googling for some information and the only thing I have found is to set the horizontalCenter and verticalCenter to 0, but this is not working for me. The panel keeps resizing from top/left corner.

Could anybody explain more clearly how to accomplish this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are currently doing this? Including the parent container. Thanks.

Comment: The source is at http://pastebin.com/3KQLBGUA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan suggests, the parent container of your Panel probably doesn't use a BasicLayout, but some liquid layout (like VerticalLayout). When you use a liquid layout you can not use absolute position attributes, like 'x', 'y', 'horizontalCenter', 'verticalCenter', 'left', 'right', 'top' or 'bottom'. They will simply be ignored, which of course makes sense because the objects have to be laid out relative to one another.

Anyway, this works perfectly:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="small" />
        <s:State name="big" />
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition>
            <s:Resize target="{panel}" />
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

    <s:Panel id="panel" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
             width.small="200" height.small="100"
             width.big="400" height.big="200">

        <s:Button label="toggle size" 
                  click="currentState = currentState == 'small' ? 'big' : 'small'" />
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that it doesn't work for me yet. Sure I'm missing something. I have a s:Group with BasicLayout, and the panel with verticalCenter and horizontalCenter="0" but do not work. If you could take a look at it I would really apreciate it. As you can see, I'm resizing the panel based on the tab selected. Don't know if this is best way to do it. Here the code http://pastebin.com/3KQLBGUA

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code 'as is' and it works as expected, so I guess the problem must be related to the parent of this component. Is it perhaps nested in an mx component?

Comment: i just tried the code you posted and it worked as expected, anchor point in the middle.

Comment: This component was created as a popup through the popup manager and you're right it was parented to the Application component that uses VerticalLayout. I thought just the parent of the panel had to be using BasicLayout. Have to do some more tests. Perhaps best option is to have another effect move position of panel in paralell, because I need the Application to have vertical layout. Thanks alo for you time (you both).

Comment: If it's in a popup you have to make sure the popup is big enough to fit the biggest size. Or you'll have to resize the popup from the center too.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer since it solved your problem.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot. I make the popup as big as the application and it works. That was a tough one for me. Thanks again. I would like to accept the answer too but I only have 11 points and it seems I'm not allowed to do so yet :/.